# Memory Error in Python 3.4.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following is my code, its giving me Memory Error:

```
with open('E:\\Book\\1900.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as readFile:
    for line in readFile:
        sepFile = readFile.read().lower()
        words_1900 = re.findall('\w+', sepFile)
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\50CommonWords.py", line 13, in <module>
sepFile = readFile.read().lower()
MemoryError
```

Comment: Apparently `E:\\Book\\1900.txt` is a very large file, what are you trying to do? why are you first iterating over its lines, and then calling `.read()` ?

Comment: You're reading the whole file into memory for each line. Why not use the `line` you already have instead?

Comment: do .read() outside the loop

Comment: Yes it is a large file (362 MB). Can you edit my code?

Comment: edit your code? You still have not told us what exactly you are trying to do with that large file.

Comment: @AnandSKumar i am trying to read this file and then want to select 50 most commonly used words. The second part i have already done on small scale text. And its working. But now the problem is when i am reading this large file it gives me Memory Error.

Comment: @SaqibAlam. `sepFile = line.lower()`

Comment: @ekhumoro its not giving me error, but its not printing the result.

Answer (score 1):

I would say instead of reading the entire file into memory, you should read the file line by line , and then use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to incrementally keep track of the words and their count in the entire file. And then at the end use the [`Counter.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method to get the 50 most common elements. Example -

```
import collections
import re
cnt = Counter()
with open('E:\\Book\\1900.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as readFile:
    for line in readFile:
        cnt.update(re.findall('\w+', line.lower()))
print("50 most common are")
print([x for x,countx in cnt.most_common(50)])       # Doing this list comprehension to only take the elements, not the count.
```

This method may also end up with MemoryError if there are lots of distinct words in the file.

Also, `Counter.most_common()` returns a list of tuples, where in each tuple the first element of the tuple is the actual word , and the second element is the count of that word.